# WCF, Serialize Json to XML

Tags: json, wcf, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

Using DataContractJsonSerializer, I was able to get Json string.
Now, I want to convert this Json(named 'stream') to XML.
Is there any way without using "[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]"?

IService

```
[OperationContract]
    string JsonSerializeFromDatabase();
[OperationContract]        
    string XmlSerializeFromJson(string strJson);
```

ClientSide

```
WCFService.Service1Client client = new WCFService.Service1Client();
string stream = client.JsonSerializeFromDatabase();
string stream2 = client.XmlSerializeFromJson(stream);
div1.InnerText = stream2;
```

ServerSide that I currently have (but no luck)

```
public string XmlSerializeFromJson(string strJson)
    {
        Stream stream1 = new FileStream("temp.xml", FileMode.Create);
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream1);
        XmlSerializerser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
        ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, strJson);

        stream1.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
        string strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        stream1.Dispose();
        stream1.Close();

        return strXml;
    }
```

Comment: WHat is in your temp.xml file? I must say I'm having difficulty seeing how your code would work

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how 'FileStream' works in detail. However, I am pretty sure that the code is working. "temp.xml" does not exist in my local folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first deserialize your json string into an instance of a type, and then create the serializer specifically to serialize the instance of the type to xml.

Something like:

```
var myInstance = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<InstanceType>(strJson);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InstanceType));
ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, myInstance);
```

Comment: I am doing performance comparison 1) GetJson 2) GetXml 3) GetXmlFromJson. There is no point to use the above code since that requires two steps.